# Image Diameter Of Uniformly Cont. Function Approach Zero As Domain Shrinks

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

Suppose we have a uniformly continuous function $f$ on some metric space $X$ and the nested sets $V_n(p)$, where $V_n(p)$ is the neighborhood of radius $1/n$ about $p$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I am trying to understand the following claim: $\textrm{diam}\,f(V_n(p)) \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Intuitively it makes sense that as the diameter of $V_n(p)$ shrinks, so should the diameter of its image. However, I do not see how the definition of uniform convergence implies that it must approach zero.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. There is some $\delta>0$ such that $d(f(x),f(y))<\varepsilon$ whenever $d(x,y)<\delta$. Now consider $n_0$ such that $n^{-1}_0<\delta$. Then $\operatorname{diam}f(V_n(p))\leqslant \varepsilon$ for all $n\geqslant n_0$.

Note that actually we just need $\delta$ such that $d(f(x),f(p))<\varepsilon$ whenever $d(x,p)<\delta$ (we will get $\operatorname{diam}f(V_n(p))\leqslant 2\varepsilon$, so continuity is enough.

Comment: I can see that if $\delta_1$ is associated with $\epsilon_1$ and $\delta_2$ with $\epsilon_2$, then $\delta_2 \leq \delta_1 \Rightarrow \epsilon_2 \leq \epsilon_1$, but I don't see why it has to approach zero.

Comment: What are $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$?

Comment: Values that satisfy $\textrm{d}(p,q)<\delta_1 \Rightarrow \textrm{d}(f(p),f(q)) < \epsilon_1$ and $\textrm{d}(p,q)<\delta_2 \Rightarrow \textrm{d}(f(p),f(q)) < \epsilon_2$

Comment: Let me try another way. I read the problem as claiming that as $\delta \rightarrow 0$ (as implied by $n \rightarrow \infty$), so must $\textrm{diam} f(V_n(p)) \rightarrow 0$. But all I see from the definition of uniform continuity is that $\textrm{diam} f(V_{n+1}(p)) \le \textrm{diam} f(V_n(p))$.